# Unable to invite friends to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to create an app that creates and invites users to an event. I can successfully create the event but I am unable to invite users to this event.

I am using the following code:

```
$.post('createEvent.php', { title: $("#evTitle").val(), start_time: aj.dateJson, location: aj.lockdownLoc.vicinity, city: aj.cityName, guests: invitees }, function(data){
    n = data.split('.');
    console.log('/'+ n[0] +'/invited?users='+invitees+'&'+n[1]);
    FB.api('/'+ n[0] +'/invited?users='+invitees+'&'+n[1],'post',function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);  // should return true
            });

        return false;
        })
```

It gives me an error: "The passed argument could not be parsed as a url.
...on(a,b){if(!FB.Dom._cssRules)FB.Dom._cssRules={};var c=true;ES5(b,'forEach',true..."

Comment: post your console log / header from the ajax call.

Comment: What's the error from the Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate the users id's with a coma

like:

```
/[EVENT ID]/invited?users=[ID1],[ID2],[ID3],[ID4]
```