# Unable to invite someone to an event

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, exception, oauth-2.0

Hi everyone here at stackoverflow,

I am trying to create a facebook application that invites the person that uses it to an event. However I can't seem to get it to work. The POST always returns the following:

"message": "(#200) ",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200

It doesn't matter if I use my PHP script or the Graph API Explorer the result is always the same.

Code:

```
$aFbConfig = array(
    'appId' => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET'
);
$oFb = new facebook($aFbConfig);

try{
    $aMe = $oFb->api('/me');
    $invite = $oFb->api('/491574947560291/invited/'.$aMe['id'], 'POST');
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($e, true).'</pre>';
}
```

Please note:

I have the required create_event permission, the exception is not caused by the /me call and 491574947560291 is a public event.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the id from your first api call? Try printing it out. As far as i remember, it will return 0 as id if you failed to get user's basic info

Comment: Yes I am getting the facebook user id & other info such as first, middle, lastname and e-mailaddress from the /me call. Also I used the Access Token Debugger. It tells me it's valid and has the create_event,email and rsvp_event permissions. I don't realy need rsvp_event but I tried to add it to the scope to see if it would solve my problem. (it didn't unfortunately)

Comment: Only just read the title - Just say there is free food and booze! Usually does the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to invite friends to event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028691/unable-to-invite-friends-to-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312375168858626).

Report to the link above that you are too experiencing this bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I hope they fix it soon because I have a deadline on this...

Answer (score 1):

The User who invites peoplo for an event has to attend that event.
User can invites own friends

Comment: If it's true what you are saying, you can't send an invitation to the person you have an access token for ? I want to invite (or sign up for that matter) the currently logged in user.